# Static member function and run time polymorphism

Tags: c++, c++11, static-members

```
class Base
{
    private:
    Base() = default;
    static Base *b;
    public:
    static Base* get();
};
class Derived: public Base
{

};
Base* Base::b=nullptr;
Base* Base::get(){Base* b = new Derived();return b;}
void main()
{
     Base* b = Base::get();  
}
```

I get a compile time error:

```
main.cpp: In static member function 'static Base* Base::get()':
main.cpp:14:41: error: use of deleted function 'Derived::Derived()'
   14 | Base* Base::get(){Base* b = new Derived();return b;}
      |                                         ^
main.cpp:9:7: note: 'Derived::Derived()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
    9 | class Derived: public Base
      |       ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:9:7: error: 'constexpr Base::Base()' is private within this context
main.cpp:4:5: note: declared private here
    4 |     Base() = default;
      |     ^~~~
```

[Live Example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c25c684236d9aef2)

In Base::get function, if i do Base* b = new Base(); or remove the private Base() constructor and make it public, i dont get any error.

Comment: Please add the compiler error message to the question.

Comment: `Base* b = new Derived();` defines a brand new variable named `b` which is distinct from `Base::b`.

Comment: Maybe because `Derived` isn't defined?  This isn't a complete example, is it?

Comment: Watch out for the memory leak here, if you call `get` twice you'll create two `Derived` instances and leak them.

Comment: The error messages tell you all you need to know - if you know how to read them.  You cannot create a `Derived` because its constructor (generated by the compiler in this case, but it would be the same if you defined one) needs to call its parent's class constructor - but that is _private_.  Anything _private_ cannot be referenced outside itself - even by a derived class.  Try declaring it `protected` if you can't just make it `public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making the Base() constructor private, the Derived() default constructor becomes ill-formed (it tries to call the private Base()), so is implicitly deleted.  You then try to use it to construct a Derived, which gives you the error you see.

In order to make this work, there needs to be a Derived() constructor -- either one you define yourself, OR arrange for the default one to not be ill-formed.  You can do the latter by making Base() public or protected instead of private (so the Derived() constructor can call it).

All the stuff with the static members and virtual functions is irrelevant.